# Checking Multiple Lists for an IP?

Tags: php

Right now I'm currently checking 1 text file for a list of IPs like this:

```
$list1 = file("../list1.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$listarray = !in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $list1);

if( $listarray ){
    ...
}
```

I would like to check 3 files, so instead of `$list1` i would have `$list1`, `$list2`, `$list3` but what would be the best way to code this and to make sure that it checks in chronological order?

Comment: Try: `$listarray = !in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],  array_merge($list1, $list2, $list3));`

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't think merging those arrays first is so efficient. Why not just use a loop?

Comment: @GolezTrol  Whats the difference between merging and a loop?

Comment: @JoeBobby I think he means this because of performance, so looping trough each array and check it is faster then merging all together and then check it

Comment: Mergin will cause a new array to be created that contains all the items from the other arrays. At that point the entire contents of the three files is not once but twice in memory, while with a loop, you just need to have one file at a time, and have it only once. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop and inside it check one file at a time. This way you will have to load only one file at a time, conserving a little memory (although these files shouldn't be too large anyway).

Now I don't know your exact use case, so I have two examples.

If you want to check whether the IP is (or is not) in *any* of these files, your loop would look like this. Inside the loop you check if the ip is in the file. If it is, set the variable to true and break the loop (no need to check the other files).

```
$inarray = false;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
  $list = file("../list$i.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
  $inarray = in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $list);
  if ($inarray) 
    break; // no need to continue checking if there is one match?
}

if ($inarray)
{
  // Your redirect code goes here.
}
```

If you need to check whether the IP is (or is not) in *each* of the files, the code inside your loop will look slightly different. Most notably, the result of `$inarray` is `and`ed with the previous results, and upon *failure* the loop is broken.

```
$inarray = true;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
  $list = file("../list$i.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
  $inarray = $inarray && in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $list);
  if (!$inarray) 
    break; // no need to continue checking if one check has failed.
}

if (!$inarray)
{
  // Your redirect code goes here.
}
```

Comment: i notice the exclam from `if( $listarray )` changed to `if ( !inarry )` is there a reason why?

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell if the way the code works is correct or not, the way i had it before it woudl check to see if an IP is in the file, if it is it would then redirect the user.. i want to do the same thing with your code but i want to check to see if an IP is in any of the 3 files so I think it would be the top part but the if statements are a little different so im not sure if it works the same way

Comment: To check for any of the files, you should use the first snippet of my answer. The if after the loop should read without `!`, so `if ($inarray) { /* redirect code here */ }` if you want to redirect if the IP is found in any of the files.

Comment: getting this error: `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/1/public_html/1/page1.php on line 7` and line 7 is `$inarray = in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $list1);`

Comment: Ah yes. I still passed `$list1` to that function, while it should just be `$list`. I removed the `1`, since there is now only one `list` variable.